# How to login to a web page without a form using TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, authentication, idhttp

I want to connect to an embedded web page using Delphi. How to login to this web page using `TIdHTTP`? I tried this code but it is not keeping the connection. The standard POST action is not included in the page. You see the page does not include a form. How do I do this? What POST is needed for this page?

This my code:

```
IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.1.139/chklogin.php?a=0&u=admin&p=123456',ms);
IdHTTP1.Connect;
ShowMessage(IdHTTP1.ResponseText);
```

I tried this way;

```
PostData := TStringList.Create; 
PostData.Add('u='+user); 
PostData.Add('pw='+password); 
PostData.Add('submit=??????? ); // <-- What goes here?
IdHTTP1.Post('192.168.1.39/login', PostData);
```

```html
[           
            function submit(){
            var pwd=$get('pw');
            var uname=$get('u');
            msgd=$get('msg');
            msgd.innerHTML='';
            if (uname.value.length===0){
                inpB=uname;
                dm("Enter Your Username");
                return;
            }else if (pwd.value.length===0){
                inpB=pwd;
                dm("Enter Your Password");
                return;
            }else{
                xmlhttpLog=$createXMLHttp();
                inpB=msgd;
                inpB.style.border="1px solid red";
                dm("Checking with TPL-Net");
                xmlhttpLog.open('GET', '/chklogin.php?a=0&u='+uname.value+'&p='+pwd.value+'&d='+$stamp(),false);
                xmlhttpLog.send(null);
                fileContent=xmlhttpLog.responseText;
                if (fileContent=='E'){
                    dm("Wrong Username/Password");
                    uname.value='';
                    pwd.value='';
                }else{
                    setCookie('tplnet',fileContent);
                    dm('Granted. Redirecting...<br>If redirection doesn\'t work click <a href="/index.html">here</a>');
                    setTimeout("window.location='/index.html';",2000);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <td>User Name:</td>
    <td><input id="u" type="text" name="uname" style="width: 150px;"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input id="pw" type="password" name="pwd" style="width: 150px;" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td height="50px" colspan="2"><a style="margin-top:20px;" class="buton" href="#" onClick="submit();">
    <span>Login</span></a>
    </td>


]
```

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT call `Connect()` manually! `Get()` handles that internally for you.

The return value of `Get()` contains the response content, `ResponseText` is not what you want.

Try this:

```
ShowMessage(IdHTTP1.Get('http://192.168.1.139/chklogin.php?a=0&u=admin&p=123456');
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is not getting back. I can already give a get back. But the connection is not keep-alive.

Comment: @metinkar keep-alives are negotiated. Add an explicit request for a keep-alive when performing `Get()`: `IdHTTP1.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';` But there is no *guarantee* the server will actually keep the connection alive on its end. HTTP is stateless, don't *rely* on keep-alives being honored.

Comment: Let me ask you again. Get() not work. How can we Post()? When i create request which value adding for submit ? For example;                                                                 PostData := TStringList.Create;
  try
    PostData.Add('u='+user);
    PostData.Add('pw='+password);
    PostData.Add('submit=??????? );<<------------
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://192.168.1.39/login', PostData);

Comment: @metinkar that is entirely dependant on what the server is expecting, but there is no `submit` value in the HTML you showed, and it clearly is using `GET` instead of `POST`. What I showed you matches what the `XMLHTTP` script is sending, except that it also sends a `d` value and you are not sending.

Comment: you're right. but i give d value it is redirecting to the login page even so. I think there's a problem with the cookie.

Comment: Because of cookies, you should `GET` the HTML page for the login form itself (and possibly also for the page you are trying to access before being prompted for login) before then submitting the login form to the server, and don't forget to set the `TIdHTTP.Request.Referer` on each request, too. It is not always trivial to mimic everything a web browser would do. That is why you should first look at a working browser's actual requests and then you can mimic them in your code as needed. Don't guess.

Comment: Date and time of the system on which the website is running is incorrect,.  Cookie is not normal. Updater device comes tomorrow. Will the system date update . Then I'il try.

Comment: Problem is solved. Adding a custom request header is required.
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('DNT','1');
 IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests','1');